# Ionic AngularFire Firebase Facebook Login

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, facebook-login, angularfire2

I meat a problem with Ionic. I will explain that.

I use Ionic 2 and AngularFire 2 to use Firebase. So I can have access to my database and login with Facebook. I use a button to call this function:

```
this.af.auth.login({
    provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
    method: AuthMethods.Popup
}).then(function(response){
    console.log('facebook login ', response);
});
```

Everything works great on the ionic lab. However, when I test my app in my device, the button does nothing, neither the Popup nor the Redirect work. So can you help me with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix some things, I used Cordova for facebook login:

You didn't share your log error, but I think you will need to do this:

In you Facebook app:
Add a new Platform, Android or IOS (You didn't say what you are using).

Add a cordova plugin:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="999999999" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

Use your facebook app id and name.

Install ionic-native in your app:

```
npm install ionic-native --save
```

Add a Facebook import in your code:

```
import { Facebook } from 'ionic-native';
```

and change your method for using a Cordova login:

```
  loginWithFacebook() {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        Facebook.login(['public_profile', 'email']).then(facebookData => {
          let provider = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(facebookData.authResponse.accessToken);
          console.log('facebook accessToken: '+facebookData.authResponse.accessToken);
          firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(provider).then(firebaseData => {
            console.log('facebook login ', firebaseData);
            observer.next();
          }).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            console.log("error");
            console.log(error);
            // ...
          });
        }, error => {
          observer.error(error);
        });
      } else {

        this.af.auth.login({
          provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
          method: AuthMethods.Popup
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log('facebook login ', response);
          observer.next();
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.info("login", error);
          observer.error(error);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Note: If your app is in development only developers can login.

Answer (score 0):

The code above can be made simpler for use inside an AuthProvider like the axample given [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/Auth-with-Ionic2.md) just by doing this:

```
signInWithFacebook(): firebase.Promise<any> {
  if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
    return Facebook.login(['public_profile', 'email']).then(facebookData => {
      let provider = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(facebookData.authResponse.accessToken);
      console.log('facebook accessToken: ' + facebookData.authResponse.accessToken);
      return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(provider);
    });
  } else {
    return this.auth$.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup
    });
  }
}
```